# Charting in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to create a chart using amchart in windows phone application.This is my code when i run i have this message"Can not implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush"how can i solve this

```
InitializeComponent();

            XDocument data = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
            var results = from query in data.Descendants("year")
                          select new ResultModel((string)query.Element("month"),
                           (int)query.Element("actual"));
            var chart = new SerialChart
            {
                CategoryValueMemberPath = "month",
                AxisForeground="White",
                 PlotAreaBackground="Black",
                  GridStroke="DarkGray"
            };
            chart.SetBinding(SerialChart.DataSourceProperty, new Binding("results"));

            var lineGraph = new LineGraph
            {
                Title = "Sales",
                ValueMemberPath = "actual",

            };

            chart.Graphs.Add(lineGraph);
            sta.Children.Add(chart);




        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The properties in SerialChart, such as AxisForeground, PlotAreaBackground, GridStroke, their type is **Brush**. So you can set it like:

```
AxisForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
PlotAreaBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
GridStroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
```